# Datasource multiple database in mysql in java

Tags: java, mysql, jakarta-ee, datasource

I already connect databse using datasource
using  
 
<Resource name="jdbc/common" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"          maxActive="50" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000" username="user" password="pass"              driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db"/>

but we have over 50 database. So I want to connect database dynamically . Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use apache commons dbcp to programatically create a data source:

```
BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
ds.setDriverClassName(DATABASE_DRIVER_CLASS);
ds.setUsername(DATABASE_USERNAME);
ds.setPassword(DATABASE_PASSWORD);
ds.setUrl(DATABASE_URL);
ds.setInitialSize(1);
ds.setMaxActive(50);
ds.setDefaultAutoCommit(false);
```

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/

Answer (score 0):

50 databases?  Do you mean "50 databases used by a single application"?

If yes - that's nuts.

Database configuration in Java EE apps is usually added to the application server (Tomcat or JBOSS).  The application does a JNDI lookup to get a reference to the data source out of a pool.

If you have fifty JNDI data sources for a single app, I'd say you should rethink your design.